# Why are additional pubkeys added to tx extra when transferring to a subaddress

Tags: transaction-data, sub-address, tx-extra

How come the regular transaction pubkey is not sufficient for subaddresses? Why do we add extra pubkeys to tx extra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal (no subaddresses involved) tx public key `R` is calculated as `rG`, but when a tx includes a destination output to a subaddress, it needs to attach a tx public key calculated as `sDi`, (`Di` being the receivers subaddress public spend key), which is *unique to the receiving subaddress*.

The rationale (and other info) is explained in [MRL-0006](https://web.getmonero.org/resources/research-lab/pubs/MRL-0006.pdf):
*"The use of separate transaction keys for each output allows Alice to include multiple outputs directed to
subaddresses."* (and of course so the wallet can relate outputs to specific subaddresses).

It should be noted, *additional* tx pub keys are not added if there's only one destination (that's a subaddress) [[ref]](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/50aa0e8b7f11680be3954c176f2daa9ccf77b7dd/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp#L396-L399), in which case it just sets a single tx public key as `sDi`.